# Difference between Collected and Shared data for Google Data Safety on Android?

Tags: android

Can anybody explain to me what is the difference between Collected and Shared data for Google Data Safety on Android?
I read the docs, but it's a little confusing. I am building a photo editor and have the option to share it on social networks or using the Share intent. But the app is not sending any data to me, it is not connected to any servers. You can just save pictures to gallery or share them.

[What to select here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPqFk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, data safety refers to how data is shared by your app with you or any third parties that you are connected to, e.g. via the use of SDKs. If a user uses an OS provided feature to share data with his contacts, this does not fall under your responsibility, and does not need to be mentioned in the Data safety form.